# Apache Storm: This script is deprecated. when run storm nimbus, supervisor, ui

Tags: apache-storm

I am fresh on Apache Storm. I just install Storm and ZooKeeper on my laptop. The ZooKeeper is going well but use the command: storm nimbus, it shows that "This script is deprecated". Please see the snapshot

[image]

Same problems when run the commands of storm supervisor and ui.

Anyone knows what is going wrong? Appreciated if anyone can help me to figure out that. Thanks~

Comment: Please include the error message in a text form

Comment: Sure, when I run "storm nimbus" command in cmd, it returns "This script is deprecated. Please use the Powershell storm.ps1 script instead". Same for supervisor and ui command. However, it can recognize "storm version" command

Comment: Do you know what is going wrong? Is the problem of storm.yaml? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you what's wrong. The script is deprecated, and you should use the Powershell script instead. In the storm/bin directory, there's a storm.cmd and a storm.ps1 script. You should use the storm.ps1 script instead of storm.cmd.

You can run the script from the normal Windows terminal with e.g. "powershell -file storm.ps1 nimbus", or if you want plain "storm nimbus" to work you can delete the storm.cmd file and Windows should automatically use the powershell script.

The background for this is that the storm.cmd script has not kept up with the Bash+Python scripts which are used in Linux, so we decided to deprecate it and replace it with a shorter Powershell script that delegates to the same Python script used in Linux. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-2558

Comment: Thank you very much